Can't locate item in Playwright
I have the following element in the code
<sp-textfield id="library-name-textfield" data-testid="library-name-textfield" quiet="" placeholder="Name" dir="ltr" type="text" focusable="">
     #shadow-root
       <input class="input" type="text" aria-describedby="sp-help-text" aria-label="Yourname" placeholder="Your name">
</sp-textfield>

I try to do the following:
await this.inputBrandLibNameTxtBox().waitFor({ state: "visible", timeout: 20000 });
await this.inputBrandLibNameTxtBox().fill(brandName);

where:
    inputBrandLibNameTxtBox = () => this.page.getByTestId("library-name-textfield").locator("input");

I get the error:
TimeoutError: locator.fill: Timeout 20000ms exceeded.
Call log:
  - waiting for getByTestId('library-name-textfield').locator('input')
  -   locator resolved to <input type="text" class="input" aria-label="Your brand name" placeholder="Your brand name" aria-describedby="sp-help-text-2f4953d1"/>
  -   fill("new-brand--1733244070919")
  - attempting fill action
  -   waiting for element to be visible, enabled and editable

How can I fix this?

Can you check whether that input is visible and is the same input you see on the page?

@hardkoded I checked the video and the input is visible on the page

And are you sure that the input you see is the same? Many webcomponents have some hidden elements and use other inputs to make them prettier.

This should work, assuming the element is actionable and not occluded by another element or scroll. Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.

I would try to debug that with good old console.log and print out if that element is returning true to isVisible() function
Other than that you can always waitFor some state changes like
await this.element.waitFor( {state: "visible"} )
Additionally you can add a bigger timeout
